# #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Tags: apache2, mysql, lamp, phpmyadmin

I am trying to setup LAMP on my OS, so I have installed `apache`, `php`, `mysql` using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install php5
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Everything works fine except that I cannot log into MySQL (which leads to `phpmyadmin` failure login). I'm getting the errors:

```
#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I googled the problem and I have also tried to reinstall all installed components, but the same result came up!

On Windows, I usually modified the content of `mysql` configuration file, but in Ubuntu nothing is the same as Windows!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that you should reset the password of root user.

### How to reset MySQL root password.

To reset your mysql password of root user, just follow these instructions.

**Step1.** Stop the mysql demon process using this command :

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

**Step2.** Start the mysqld demon process using the --skip-grant-tables option with this command:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

**Step3.** Start the mysql client process using this command:

```
mysql -u root
```

**Step4.** From the mysql prompt execute this command to be able to change any password:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**Step5.** Then reset/update your password and quit:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');
quit
```

**Step6.** Start the mysql demon process using this command :

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Now, you can log in to MySQL as root user.

Comment: thanks, that worked well and also found something else that in my re-installation i typed `sudo apt-get remove mysql-server` which removed mysql-server but keeps the config files so in my next installation it loads the last one's config files so the result would be the same! i just should type `apt-get --purge mysql-server` instead :)

Comment: After Step3 i get error "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
[1]+  Exit 1                  sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
" on Ubuntu 16.04